# Get the last line of a file while it keeps getting updated

Tags: python

How do i just read the last line, while a file is getting updated? I saw solution which waited for one second to read again. But i want to run a function each time a line is added if the line contains a chasephrase?
How do i do that?
I tried the following

```
f1 = open('file.txt', 'r')
while True:
    for line in f1:
        pass
    print(line)
```

which prints me the last line constantly. How do i implement this functionality while it only do something (print in the moment) once a new line is added and only once?

Comment: `lastLine = f1[-1]`

Comment: i get the error message _io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Oh sorry by f1 i meant file after you read it.

Comment: If you just iterate on the file, Python will read the file until EOF as normally that is what you'd want. Instead of doing that you can read the file manually, using f.read() and keep up with the updates.


I'll put this in a pastebin since the question got closed: https://pastebin.com/Xvvcr7BW